# Request ending early on ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, curl

```
router.route('...')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  // This job() function doing some *long* async task and end of the task calling 3th param as callback     
  job(param1, param2, function(response) {
    // printing response to console perfectly
    console.log("callback fired", response);
    res.send("response");
  }); 
});
```

And I'm making my request with `curl`.

```
$ curl ... -m 300
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

cURL is waiting for a response for a few minutes and then I'm getting *empty reply* error. cURL is giving this error **before** nodejs printing *callback fired* message.

Same error if I make this request with a browser or with Postman.

I'm sure there are no `res.send()`, `res.end()` functions inside `job()` async function. I stuck, how can I track and found the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible timeouts that could be affecting you.  Without seeing the actual network trace (to see what happens when the request ends), I can't tell which timeout might be causing your issue.  But, you can just address both of them and it should handle your issue.

First, `curl` has a timeout value.  It is unclear what its default setting is, but you can set whatever value you want with:

```
curl --max-time 900
```

where the value is in seconds.

Second, the nodejs http server has a timeout where if no response is sent to an open request, it will close the socket (this keeps dead sockets from building up over time).  You can see the doc for `server.setTimeout()` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback).  The default for the http server object is 2 minutes (I don't know if Express changes that at all).

The general idea is this:

```
 server.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);   // set response timeout to 10 minutes
```

where the `server` object would be your http server object (not the Express `app` object).

Comment: as you guess my problem was http server's default timeout setting. So I increase that value from 2 minutes to 5 minutes and my problem solved. Thank you.